# Twitter Powershell API

Tags: powershell, twitter

I am unsure if PowerShell is really even the correct medium for this and so appreciate anyone saying stop, do this instead!

My aim is to search the last one hours twitter feeds for a list of specific terms lets say `Ford, Crysler, Ferrari`

From there I want to do two things:

1. count the number of times each of these have been mentioned in the time period to see what is on trend.
2. download the list of these tweets and the account posting them.

I have managed to set up an OAuth for Twitter and using web found code, replicate their utilization of this for sending a tweet but I do not get how I can search?

Provided with what I have, clueless at this stage any help or useful resources?

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Security")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net")

$status = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("My first tweet from Powershell");  ### This can be utilised to possibly retweet... 
$oauth_consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$oauth_consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$oauth_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$oauth_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$oauth_nonce = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes([System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks.ToString()));
$ts = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow - [System.DateTime]::ParseExact("01/01/1970", "dd/MM/yyyy", $null).ToUniversalTime();
$oauth_timestamp = [System.Convert]::ToInt64($ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();

$signature = "POST&";
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json") + "&";
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_consumer_key=" + $oauth_consumer_key + "&");
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_nonce=" + $oauth_nonce + "&"); 
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&");
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_timestamp=" + $oauth_timestamp + "&");
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_token=" + $oauth_token + "&");
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("oauth_version=1.0&");
$signature += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("status=" + $status);

$signature_key = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_consumer_secret) + "&" + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_token_secret);

$hmacsha1 = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1;
$hmacsha1.Key = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($signature_key);
$oauth_signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hmacsha1.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($signature)));

$oauth_authorization = 'OAuth ';
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_consumer_key="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_consumer_key) + '",';
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_nonce="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_nonce) + '",';
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_signature="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_signature) + '",';
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",'
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_timestamp="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_timestamp) + '",'
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_token="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_token) + '",';
$oauth_authorization += 'oauth_version="1.0"';

$post_body = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("status=" + $status); 
[System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");
$request.Method = "POST";
$request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $oauth_authorization);
$request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$body = $request.GetRequestStream();
$body.write($post_body, 0, $post_body.length);
$body.flush();
$body.close();
$response = $request.GetResponse();
```

This sends a tweet and looking through the other documentation the closest I have got is...

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Security")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net")

$oauth_consumer_key = "Z94j23TcYmokjBDCxkym0NiHV";
$oauth_consumer_secret = "rFuQSD61VF0BUu3j4DKqRxOSFyhQfZ7xvw8Nk0qmYT1kMAOTNP";
$oauth_token = "275049815-pP4QyXIZP9jA1P6zBB8MpFAFs3Rmsa8wal2MIMRb";
$oauth_token_secret = "BXw0WmjE3EIcSnkbuZv7uKR8io0mplpZ9Nk5hRlwd7ieq";
$oauth_nonce = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes([System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks.ToString()));
$ts = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow - [System.DateTime]::ParseExact("01/01/1970", "dd/MM/yyyy", $null).ToUniversalTime();
$oauth_timestamp = [System.Convert]::ToInt64($ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::CreateHttp("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi")
$req = $request.RequestUri
$wreq = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $req
$wreq
```

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSTwitter/1.0.0.2 ? https://github.com/MyTwitter/MyTwitter ?

Comment: Use my module 'Import-Module PSTwitterAPI' it does all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ive never worked with the twitter api, but with other api's I have used it might look something like this.

adding the token to the endo of the url has always worked better than trying to pass it any other way(not sure why).

```
$url = 'https://url.com/something?token=$token' 
$body=@{
    foo=bar,
    foo2=bar2
    }
$req = invoke-restmethod -method get -uri $url -body $body |?{$_.value -like 'Ford'}
```